# Lock landscape orientation in Swift iOS9

Tags: ios, swift

I'm struggling with locking my app in landscape mode. I only have one ViewController, and it's not in a NavigationController. Inside the view controller I have the following code:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft
}
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false;
}
override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft
}
```

In the "General" tab of the settings I have the following:

[image: General]

And in the ViewController's attributes I have this:

[image: Attributes]

I've tried using UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(...) in the ViewDidLoad, but that had no effect. I'm trying to run this app on an iPad mini and I'm totally at a loss. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** I finally found the answer to this. In the "Supporting Files" folder, the info.plist file has attributes for "Supported Interface Orientations" and "Supported Interface Orientations (iPad)".

[image]

Evidently this was overriding all my other selections and code, since I was running the app on an iPad. Removing the unwanted orientations fixed my issue. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I tried this and it works perfectly when I run the app on iPad. But when I am uploading my archive to the app store it says that I need all the orientations for iPad. Any help would be greatly appreciated.